# Problem with temperature units regarding heat balance calculation

Tags: thermodynamics

So, guys, I realized that I came up with many irrelevant information which I deleted in order to keep it as clear it can be. I'm just interested in this simple problem: if I want to calculate the sensible heat of a warm body, let's assume it's 100kg of water at 100°C. Q=m*cp*∆T, but I don't know the initial water temperature from which I raise it up to 100°C. In this case, if Q is reffered as the sensible heat of the water, should I consider 0°C and calculate it as Q=100*cp*100? Because another idea is to consider starting temperature  0K and calculate it as Q=100*cp*373, which are obvious different results (but the second seems unrealistic to me).

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us your calculation in detail?  It is not clear exactly what you did.

Comment: Make sure that you are getting the same temperature difference in both temperature units.  And, note that $Q=mc_p\Delta T$, not $Q=mc_pT$.

Comment: Yes, sure, but I separately calculate them as inlet/outlet streams. Inlet=Outlet and it should be the same, right?

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se], Alin! I've converted the extra information that you posted as an answer into an edit to your question. You should see an "edit" link below the question if you want to make further changes.

Comment: If you are going to use the total enthalpy of each stream, you can use any base temperature that is convenient.  Calculating enthalpy relative to zero Celsius is fine, and calculating enthalpy relative to zero Kelvins is fine, as long as you are consistent in the calculation.  I suggest using the same reference temperature as any data tables that you are using.  And note: Q is used for heat transfer, while H is used for total enthalpy.  This means that $Q=\Delta H$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer I'm about to give.  It is just a request for clarification.

So you have $$\dot{m}_{solution\ in}+\dot{m}_{steam\ in}=\dot{m}_{solution\ out}+\dot{m}_{gas\ out}$$and 
$$\dot{m}_{solution\ in}H_{solution\ in}+\dot{m}_{steam\ in}H_{{steam\ in}}=\dot{m}_{solution\ out}H_{solution\ out}+\dot{m}_{gas\ out}H_{gas\ out}$$
Are these the mass- and enthalpy balances you used?

Comment: I edited my post, but yes, this is the way the heat of the steam is expressed in my problem. The heat of the (solution in) is calculated as Q=m*cp*T. And my actual question is what unit I use for T in this equation. I explained it in more detail in my edited post.

Comment: No matter what you choose as the reference temperature, the answer should come out the same.  So the problem must be with how you are expressing the enthalpy of each stream as a function of temperature and composition.  How do you take into account the heat of solution of SO2 in water, and, in the case of the gas streams, are you also including the sensible heat required to raise the temperature to 100 C as well as the latent heat of vaporization?  You have not provided enough information on the data you have given to determine the enthalpy of the various streams.

Comment: Ok, so I added an image to make it clear. I've only used the latent heat in order to calculate Qsteam used for desorption, I've used entalpy to calculate the inlet Qsteam, and for the others inlet/outlet flows I used Q=m*cp*T, where T is the actual temperature of the flow. I used some indication for calculus, but now I doubt more things.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact problem statement from your textbook.